# Referring inner properties in the IF condition - JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

The following is a sample schema to depict the issue

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "person": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "age": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "child": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/person"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "child"
    ],
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "person/age": {
                "const": "3"
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "guardian": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/person"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "guardian"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to refer age inside the person object?

`{"child":{"age":"3"}}`. Should fail as guardian tag is missing

The above data should fail as the guardian object is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `if` is just a regular schema validating against the instance. Just nest your `properties` like you would with any nested object structure.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "child": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "age": { "const": "3" }
      },
      "required": ["age"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["child"]
}
```

Note that the `type` and `required` keywords are necessary to not inadvertently trigger the `then` schema. For example, with out them, these would cause the `then` to trigger when you probably didn't want it to.

```json
{}
```

```json
{ "child": null }
```

```json
{ "child": {} }
```

Comment: How is `type` helping when there is `required` , shouldn't required cover their types too?

Comment: `required` only applies if the instance is an object. Most keywords only apply to certain types of data.